# Is there a supported way to glean properties from a nib file without initializing an actual object?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, interface-builder, xib

I have a XIB file and I want to get the `frame` property of the first object inside it without actually unarchiving the nib and instantiating an object from it.

I know XIB's are just XML and this can be done, but I'm wondering if there's a supported way of doing this, something that won't break if/when Apple changes the XIB file structure.

The reason is quite simple, I have a XIB for a `UITableViewCell` and in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` I want to return whatever the height was that I set in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a reliable way of doing it without instantiating the contents.

You should hold a variable for the height, initially set to -1 or similar and when you do load the NIB check and update the value. Arguably you could do this up front as the cell could just be added to the reuse pool so you wouldn't be increasing your overall memory usage.

Comment: That would work... If UITableView asks the delegate for the cell before it asks for the height, does it? (reliably so?)

Comment: No, it asks for the height first. But if the cell is registered with the table view you just dequeue an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a supported way I know of. 
The idea with the nib is that you don't need to know you can set the value in awakeFromNib

You could also simply hard code it or store it in a plist for use in awakeFromNib